# CorrelationId in Azure functions v2

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions

I want to have a correlationId to be able to follow a request on Application insights and other places. I have installed the [correlationId nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CorrelationId/) on my MVC part of the solution. How do I follow the same Id on my Azure functions?

As an example let's say user calls an API and that API will have a correlationId: xxxx-1 then as a part of the request, it writes to service bus that will be picked up by an Azure function:

```
[FunctionName("func1")]
public async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("topic","subscription", Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString")] Message message)
{
 log.LogInformation("This is log");
}
```

How do I apply the correlationId in the function's context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access the correlation id for that message with the `CorrelationId` property. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.message.correlationid?view=azure-dotnet).

```
[FunctionName("func1")]
public async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("topic","subscription", Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString")]
    Message message)
{
 var id = message.CorrelationId;
}
```